# GroupConcat when string comma separated values are not equal (reporting status changes for an item)

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let’s say I have a table that has a Column that shows the status of an item every time it moved from one location to another location.

Tb1

```
+----------+---------------------------------+------------+
| ItemName |             Status              | Locations  |
+----------+---------------------------------+------------+
| Item1    | Active, Active, Active, Active  | A, B, C, D |
| Item2    | Active, Active, InTransit       | R, G, H    |
| Item3    | Active, Offline, Active, Active | R, T, Y, U |
+----------+---------------------------------+------------+
```

I need to create a report in which I use a query to extract a string (ItemPath) that shows the Location the Item moves to every time and the Status of the Item every time there is a change in status only.

For example, when status did not change the output needs to look something like this:

```
+----------+-----------------------------+
| ItemName |          ItemPath           |
+----------+-----------------------------+
| Item1    | (Active)A --> B --> C --> D |
+----------+-----------------------------+
```

But if there is a change of Status during the reporting period from which I am pulling data for, then the ItemPath would like this:

```
+----------+----------------------------------+
| ItemName |             ItemPath             |
+----------+----------------------------------+
| Item1    | (Active)A --> B --> C --> D      |
| Item2    | (Active)R --> G --> (InTransit)H |
+----------+----------------------------------+
```

Notice that is the Status does not change from one Location to the next, the Status is not reported

So far, I have the following:

```
 ‘(‘ || tb1.Status|| ‘)’ || groupconcat(tb1.Locations, ‘—>’)
```

The problem with this, is that it will concatenate every Status, not only when a status changes. With my current solution, the ItemPath string looks like this:

```
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| ItemName |                      ItemPath                       |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| Item1    | (Active)A --> (Active)B --> (Active)C --> (Active)D |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Any guidance is extremely appreciated, I have tried looking up a solution but haven’t found one that works. I am using sqlite.

Comment: Wouldn't your current solution produce `(Active, Active, Active Active)A, B, C ,D` as there is nothing here to `groupconcat`... like you aren't aggregating any data. You actually want the opposite of `group_concat`, which isn't easy. This is why it's considered bad practice to store lists in a field.

Comment: That makes sense about storing lists in a field. The original table from which I get Status information is not string a list of statuses per item...each item has a status depending on the timestamp of when the item was placed at a different location. I've seen solutions where you can get the previous and next values for an object but how would I iterate over all the rows of a given item to track the changes in status?